# Spring Boot 3 Data JPA EntityManagerFactory can't be found in Unit Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I had an old Spring Application for a personal project and I converted it to Spring Boot later and still kept a lot of legacy XML files which worked.   I decided to archive this project on GitHub and create a very NEW very normal Spring Boot 3 application with Spring Data JPA.
I created this application with the Spring Starter initializer as one does, and yep, I did include Spring Data JPA.  The idea eventually is to put this in a Docker Container as a Microservice and deploy to my Amazon ECR Service.

I have been following the documentation for Spring Data JPA, and I think the problem is strictly in my unit test.   The problem is that the unit test cannot find my DAO or Repository.   So, let me start by adding the files that I have so far:

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library_db?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

@SpringBootApplication
public class LibraryApplication  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LibraryApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.tomholmes.products.library")
@EntityScan("com.tomholmes.products.library.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.tomholmes.products.library.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration  {
}

public interface BookDao extends JpaRepository<BookEntity, Long> {
}

@Transactional
@SpringBootTest(classes = { LibraryApplication.class, DatabaseConfiguration.class })
public class BookDaoTest  {
    @Autowired
    private BookDao bookDao;

    @Test
    public void testFindById() {
        long bookId = 2;
        BookEntity book = bookDao.findById(bookId).orElse(null);
        assertNotNull(book);
        assertEquals(bookId, book.getBookId());
    }
}
```

This test and others like it is to ensure that the basic database configuration in Spring Boot 3 with Spring Data JPA is configured correctly.  I think the problem I am having ultimately is in the test itself.   Most of the other StackOverflow posts I have seen and others are still focused on Spring Boot 2 and not 3, even though they should be very similar.

The problem I am having in my unit test is this error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

From all the research I did today, the entityManagerFactory is defined in the JPARepository, so it shouldn't have to be specifically defined.   I just don't know why this error is even coming up.

I know I didn't add the pom.xml or the entity code itself, but if you need those I can provide them.

Comment: I guess the `EntityManagerFactory` bean is being created in another `@Configuration` class. Try using `@DataJpaTest` annotation instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found answer with some more trial and error, but the response from Semyon gave me some more direction.

So, the pom.xml has this originally:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

and I changed it to just:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

and this solved the problem with the entityManagerFactory issue, that got resolved.   I also changed the test header to:

@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace =
AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class BookDaoTest {

The @DataJpaTest annotation does exactly what I needed to do, which is just test the database as an integration test.  Yes, we really insert, update, and delete, but this annotation rolls back at the end of every test which is what we want.

Since I am using a real MySQL database running locally on my laptop, then I had to add the annotation:
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
and it seems the parameter:
replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE
means to not replace the database with an embedded database.

I think this is going to solve the issues for me.